# find all the strings string with Dev_ and end with a number with 3 digits or less

Tags: sed

I am trying to fit sed to my use case
I have a list of string all starting with FP_ or DEV_ .... and ending with some numbers
I need to find all the items where they start with Dev_ and ends with numbers of 3 digits or less so for example this one wont be accepted then

```
Dev_xxxxx-1111
```

but this is accepted and should be kept in the list

```
Dev_xxxxx-111
```

I am trying this

```
sed -e 's/  ",'${IMAGETAG}/Dev/
```

which gives me all the string starting with Dev and that fix half of the issue but cannot filter out and exclude the ones ends with more than 3 digits
so here is what I need
here is my input

```
[ "1.3.0.0-amd64", "Dev_04938095cc4bcefb1f85d7b306c1c49d335e80ce_167075", "Dev_08346f824a146dafbdca4b63eb3ce0b1549c6346_165", "Dev_0ab8997f5d45ed6b7515b5148d492c98109bf94a_16"]
```

and output should be

```
[ "Dev_08346f824a146dafbdca4b63eb3ce0b1549c6346_165", "Dev_0ab8997f5d45ed6b7515b5148d492c98109bf94a_16"]
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: With GNU `awk`: `awk 'BEGIN{ FPAT="\"(Fp|Dev)_[^_]*_[0-9]{1,3}\""; OFS=", " } { $1=$1; print "[ " $0 "]" }'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your strings are for example in a file, you can use `grep` instead of sed to match the whole line using

```
grep -E "^(Fp|Dev)_(.*[^0-9])?[0-9]{1,3}$" file
```

See the regex matches [here](https://regex101.com/r/8cua62/1).

An example in bash matching anything between 2 underscores and ending with 1-3 digits:

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=("1.3.0.0-amd64" "Dev_04938095cc4bcefb1f85d7b306c1c49d335e80ce_167075" "Dev_08346f824a146dafbdca4b63eb3ce0b1549c6346_165" "Dev_0ab8997f5d45ed6b7515b5148d492c98109bf94a_16")

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   if [[ $i =~ ^(Fp|Dev)_.*_[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]; then
    echo "Match: $i"
else 
    echo "No match: $i"
fi
done
```

Output

```
No match: 1.3.0.0-amd64
No match: Dev_04938095cc4bcefb1f85d7b306c1c49d335e80ce_167075
Match: Dev_08346f824a146dafbdca4b63eb3ce0b1549c6346_165
Match: Dev_0ab8997f5d45ed6b7515b5148d492c98109bf94a_16
```

See the regex matches [here](https://regex101.com/r/CQWIJK/1).

Comment: unfortunately they are not in a file is there a way to the match in sed?

Comment: @Learner Where do your strings come from? Do you want to do any replacement on them, or just match them? Do you want to match whole strings? Or a part of a string?

Comment: They are coming as a response of an api and yes I do some replacement and the put the result in a variable latest_tag

Comment: also with your approach how can I match this pattern?
Dev_f64db4c58d6a0eddeec3c12c74d5fbba1849886d_16620
so anything can come in between the two underline like f64db4c58d6a0eddeec3c12c74d5fbba1849886d

Comment: @Learner Like this? `^(Fp|Dev)_(.*[^0-9])?[0-9]+$` https://regex101.com/r/RWPiW3/1 or `^(Fp|Dev)_.*_[0-9]+$` https://regex101.com/r/dM8u8U/1

Comment: @Learner Are you doing this in bash?

Comment: Yes it is in bash and your regex also matches 
1.3.0.0-amd64
Dev_04938095cc4bcefb1f85d7b306c1c49d335e80ce_167075
which I want them excluded and not returned
so this part _167075 needs a check and if it is more than 3 digits I want it excluded

Comment: @Learner So you want to match 1-5 digits then `^(Fp|Dev)_.*_[0-9]{1,5}$` https://regex101.com/r/0gUSQQ/1 or like `^(Fp|Dev)_.*_[0-9]{1,3}$` https://regex101.com/r/ywyDD4/1

Comment: thanks yea that looks good but when I try this and print test nothing returns 
test=$(grep -E "^(Fp|Dev)_.*_[0-9]{1,4}$" test.txt)

Comment: @Learner See https://tio.run/##Tc7LTsMwEAXQvb9iarJoEU3t@hFbqBILxA5@IEojjx9KJJqgtGJTyq8HZwFiObr3zAy6czfPd6sd9sMO80CIm6bDmvJSlKxkW3cKWlKgz/GzZdIKw6zyXqKPCXkyKlQomPbcSxuEUNEwH1uuK1apX2WE1MnspeNSB5cweCdRi4jCR4ZcSet1rmT1Rxwaa6ukglQxaKwUV6i4NEHavbeGM4vJSpcJ3RCSxgl66AegxTV/Xz81N0rCSACgT1DXUPRw@Ibj@uXjK6/ftOV9W7Otba78QdwKaJpHuHRxWABE341AX93Fd6sMKYnv5wj/orcRTksKy9mlkPp8bIjz/AM

Comment: https://tio.ru is pretty cool, didn't know about this one

Comment: @anubhava ITYM http://tio.run

Answer (score 1):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    hits = sep = ""
    while ( match($0,/"Dev_[^"]*_[0-9]{,3}"/) ) {
        hits = hits sep substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        sep = ", "
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}
hits {
    print "[ " hits "]"
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
[ "Dev_08346f824a146dafbdca4b63eb3ce0b1549c6346_165", "Dev_0ab8997f5d45ed6b7515b5148d492c98109bf94a_16"]
```

Answer (score 0):

the formatting should be trivial from here on :

```
mawk '/^[[]| *[]]\n$|Dev_.+_[0-9]([0-9][0-9]?)?$/' \
                  \
     ORS=' ' RS='[ \t]*\"(,[ \t]+\"[ \t]*)?'
```

---

```
# it's only a space between the 2 lines, 
# but reformatted for readability. Ditto for 2nd code below

[ Dev_08346f824a146dafbdca4b63eb3ce0b1549c6346_165        
  Dev_0ab8997f5d45ed6b7515b5148d492c98109bf94a_16 ]
```

or more simply, just

```
gawk '/[][]|^Dev_.+_[0-9]{1,3}$/' RS='"' ORS=' '
```

---

```
[  Dev_08346f824a146dafbdca4b63eb3ce0b1549c6346_165 
   Dev_0ab8997f5d45ed6b7515b5148d492c98109bf94a_16 ]
```